# Delete duplicated rows, selecting specific values to retain

Tags: r, duplicates, data-manipulation

I am working on a raw dataset that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", 
                                "Beta","Beta", "Beta","Beta" ), 
                 "Year" = c(1970, 1970, 1980, 1990, 1970, 1980, 
                            1980,1990), 
                 "Val" = c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1),
                 "Val2" = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1),
                 "Val3" = c(0,2.34,1.3,0,0,2.34,3.2,1.3))
```

The data is a bit dirty as I have multiple observations for each ID and Year identifier - e.g. I have 2 different rows for Alpha in 1970. The same holds for Beta in 1980.

The issue is that the variable of interest `Val` `Val2` `Val3` have different scores in the duplicated rows (in terms of id/year).

I would like to find a concise way to produce the following final dataframe:

```
final<- data.frame("ID" = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha", 
                           "Beta", "Beta","Beta" ), 
                  "Year" = c( 1970, 1980, 1990, 1970, 
                             1980,1990), 
                  "Val" = c(1,1,1,0,0,1),
                  "Val2" = c(0,0,1,0,1,1),
                  "Val3" = c(2.34,1,0,0,3.2,1.3))

final
```

The logic is the following:

1) I want to have only one obs for every ID/year

2) For each variable of interest(`Val` `Val2` `Val3`), I want only to retain the observation with the higher value in the single ID/year output

To illustrate. In `df` there is a duplicated observation for Alpha/1970. I want to reduce this to a single row. `Val` takes the value of 0 and 1, and in the `final` dataframe only 1 is retained.    `Val2` takes the value of 0 and 0, so I simply keep 0 in  `final`. `Val2` takes the value of 2.34 and 1, hence I want to retain in the `final` dataframe.

I guess I could do this one column at the time using this data.table command

```
library(dplyr)
val1<- df %>% select(ID:Val)
library(data.table)
setDT(val1)[order(-Val)][,.SD[1,], by = .(ID, Year)]
val2<- df %>% select(ID,Year,Val2)
library(data.table)
setDT(val2)[order(-Val2)][,.SD[1,], by = .(ID, Year)]
```

and then merge the values together but there are several columns for which I have to run the operation and I was looking for a more concise way to do it.

I hope it is sufficiently clear

Thanks a lot for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Year) %>% 
  summarise_all(max)
  # for specific set of columns, use `summarise_at`
  # summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Val")), max)
```

---

or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep('^Val\\d*$", names(df))
setDT(df)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, max), .(ID, Year), .SDcols = nm1]
```

Comment: Great very effective! Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the `summarise_all(max)` to a specific set of variables?

Comment: @Alex You can use `summarise_at` (updated as commented)

Comment: great! super eseful

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
aggregate(. ~ ID + Year, FUN =  max, data = df)

     ID Year Val Val2 Val3
1 Alpha 1970   1    0 2.34
2  Beta 1970   0    0 0.00
3 Alpha 1980   1    0 1.30
4  Beta 1980   0    1 3.20
5 Alpha 1990   1    1 0.00
6  Beta 1990   1    1 1.30
```